# How to use replace function for setAs() in R?

Tags: r, oop, coerce, r-s4

I am trying to define a coerce method in R including a replace function. Unfortunately, neither the documentation of `setAs()` nor further discussions on the internet clarify the way how to use the parameter **replace** in this function.

My target is to get a coerce method working the same in these two commands:

```r
obj <- as(obj, "to-class")
as(obj) <- "to-class"
```

For instance, I set a method to coerce the class "table" to "data.frame", including a function for a replacement method:

```r
setAs(from = "table", to = "data.frame",
    def = function(from) {
      return(as.data.frame(from))
    },
    replace = function(from, value) {
      from <- as(from, value)
      return(from)
    })
```

Now the method in action

```r
data(Titanic)
x <- Titanic

# two coerce alternatives
y <- as(x, "data.frame")
as(x) <- "data.frame"
```

While the first works perfect, the second retrieves me an error:

> `Error in .identC(.class1(value), Class) :`
>   `argument "Class" is missing, with no default`

Am I doing something wrong or maybe expecting too much from `setAs()`?

Answer (score 2):

`replace` doesn't do what you think it does. It exists to allow direct assignment of an uncoerced object into a coerced version. The second argument is not supposed to be the class name, but an uncoerced object.

To take your table / data.frame coercion, we could write.

```r
setAs(from = "table", to = "data.frame",
      def = function(from) {
        return(as.data.frame(from))
      },
      replace = function(from, value) {
        from <- as.data.frame(value)
        return(from)
      })
```

So if we have a table called `x`

```r
x <- table(iris$Species)
x

#> setosa versicolor  virginica 
#>     50         50         50
```

We can assign a different table's data *and* coerce to a data.frame in one go by doing:

```
as(x, "data.frame") <- table(mtcars$cyl)
x
#>   Var1 Freq
#> 1    4   11
#> 2    6    7
#> 3    8   14
```

Effectively, it's the same as writing

```r
x <- as(table(mtcars$cyl), "data.frame")
```

and therefore of limited utility, which is perhaps why the documentation is scant.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I supposed that its use was rare.

Answer (score 1):

`as` requires object and class, so:

```
as(x, "data.frame") <- x
```

Comment: This gives me `Error in while (sig[[n]] == "ANY") n <- n - 1 : 
  the condition has length > 1` and I am looking for a way to avoid calling the object twice in the command line.

Comment: Despite my comment, this was an important hint to solve the issue (see my own answer).

Answer (score 0):

While I still don't have any clue about what is the parameter **replace** in `setAs()` good for, I solved the issue defining a method for `as()<-`:

```r
# Defining 'as()'
setAs(from = "table", to = "data.frame",
    def = function(from) {
      return(as.data.frame(from))
    })

# Defining 'as()<-'
setReplaceMethod("as", signature(object = "table", Class = "missing",
        value = "character"), 
    function(object, Class, value) {
      object <- as(object, value)
      return(object)
    })
```

The nice thing in this solution, the replace method will apply for any coercion defined with `from = "table"`